# 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Hydrated Document

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types, typescript-generics

```
async delete(id: string): Promise<T> {
        try {
            const response = await this._model.findByIdAndDelete(id);
            return response;
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
        }
    };
```

I am getting the below error while returning the response

Type 'HydratedDocument<T, {}, {}> | null' is not assignable to type 'T'.
'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'HydratedDocument<T, {}, {}> | null'.

also why is this type of error occurring?

Comment: What is `findByIdAndDelete` and `HydratedDocument`?

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.  Right now all I get are errors unrelated to your question because the types and values involved have not been defined.

Comment: You need to update the code when you return response like this ==> response ? response.toObject() : null;

Comment: When I write code like const response: T = await this._model.findByIdAndDelete(id).lean(); then error is resolved. But don't know why this kind of error is occurring

Comment: Without a [mre] I'm not prepared to make a guess about what's happening.